# Question ban without any reason

Tags: discussion, support, post-ban

I got a question ban on Physics SE. The reason stated was that most of my questions did not met the guidelines. However, most of my questions have positive votes. What is the reason for the ban?

Comment: I guess you have a number of downvoted [deleted questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-questions/355398). Despite you or the system deleting them, they are still your questions so I imagine that things are not really as rosy as you claim. Your best bet is to improve and undelete those questions if you can.

Comment: Considering [you posted a question on Physics.SE two hours after asking this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/767790/265250), you were either *only just* question-banned and managed to climb your way out of it, or you weren't question-banned at all.

Comment: Sounds like you're not understanding how StackExchange works, or the house rules. Your claim of "not any reason" is vanity talking, and the community does not agree. That's a deal-breaker problem that you need to resolve if you wish to contribute successfully.  Hint: why do you like this site, as opposed to say, 4channel?  Quality, right? How do you think quality gets upheld?

Answer (score 11):

Just looking at your non-deleted questions, you've got four questions with negative scores and seven closed questions, out of a total of 27 non-deleted questions.  That's not exactly "without any reason".  If you've had any questions deleted, that also counts against you, making your situation even worse.

It might be possible to clarify your question about the paradoxical velocity-time graph (explain *why* you think it is clearly wrong) and get it re-opened.  Other than that, your only option is to wait out the ban and concentrate on asking good, non-homework questions.